# The map marker does not work

Tags: far-cry-3

In one of the first missions, I'm supposed to move the map marker to the hunting grounds. I move the marker to the flashing icon, but nothing happens... Why? Does anybody know?

I'm playing on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing X (I think it is X button) then it will place a marker. Or just walk to the flashing icon, without placing anything.